# How to test AngularJS App using Karma/Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Till now I have been reading the Angular JS official docs, and some other sites which have demonstrated Unit testing in Angular JS. But all of them have just started the explanation with an example file which contains some test code. But nowhere could I find the Pre-steps to write the unit testing code. Something like, where do we write our test cases? any Specific folder location? How to run the tests etc. Can anyone please guide?

Really appreciate the help and time spent on the question.

Answer (score 1):

The question where to put the unit tests is more like a matter of personal taste and which directory layout you choose. I prefer a feature-driven layout, putting all files for a feature in a directory and that includes the unit tests as well. If you do that, you have to follow certain naming conventions like:

```
myfeature.module.js
myfeature.controller.js
myfeature.controller.spec.js /* this is the unit test */
myfeature.html
myfeature.less
```

I suggest reading the [angular styleguide from John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguid) and if you want to get kickstarted, use one of the generators out there. In my one ([cc-angular](http://github.com/leanovate/generator-cc-angular)) I tried to stick to these rules and jasmine with karma and e2e tests are built in.